# Can we override an interface method with visibility that is not public?

Tags: interface

Could you please just provide a simple yes/no answer. It would be sufficient and much appreciated.

Comment: .............No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method signature you defined in interface has public access specifier then you have to override that method, with the same method signature (that means with public access specifier) whenever you implement the interface to any class.

Answer (score 1):

No. We cannot override an interface method if it's visibility is not public.
And if it has its visibility as public then you can override it with the same method signature (i.e., with the same access specifier public) whenever you implement the interface to any class.